# Adding textbox in SQL Reporting services (Dynamically)

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am having a problem like that i am having some 10 parameters. I am dispalying the parameter values in the textbox(10 different). I need to display the textbox based on my parameter values

If the parameter has values - show them in textbox
If the parameter has no values - hide the textbox.

Currently I am using this above mentiond method. (using hidden functionlity).

Please let me know some other options that we can do this like dynamically creating the 
controls(textbox) based on parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services does not have an event based model that would allow you to hook in custom code in order to dynamically create report objects. Using expressions to hide and show objects is the correct way of achieving this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the default report viewer control that comes with SSRS supports this. You may have to build your own report viewer interface that calls the reporting services manually.